# TaskDialogIndirect randomly fails and makes empty, undrendered window

Tags: c++, windows, c++14, comctl32

I use `TaskDialogIndirect()` to display more advanced Error Messages. I can customize the buttons, icons, and more.

The problem is that, sometimes it makes these invisible empty dialog boxes.

I need it to be reliable. I am wondering why this is even happening in the first place.

Example of it failing (there is no visible window):

[image]

Here is the code that makes the dialogs (not production code):

```
int MessageBoxPosL(HWND hWnd, LPCTSTR lpText, LPCTSTR lpCaption, UINT uType, int X, int Y)
{
    TaskDialogData data;
    data.X = X;
    data.Y = Y;

    TASKDIALOGCONFIG config = {};
    config.cbSize = sizeof(config);
    config.hwndParent = hWnd;
    config.pszWindowTitle = lpCaption;
    config.pszContent = lpText;
    // configure other settings as desired, based on uType...
    config.pfCallback = &TaskDialogCallback;
    config.lpCallbackData = (LONG_PTR)&data;
    config.dwFlags = TDF_ENABLE_HYPERLINKS;
    config.hFooterIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_ERROR);
    config.dwCommonButtons = ButtonActive(TDCBF_YES_BUTTON) | ButtonActive(TDCBF_NO_BUTTON) | ButtonActive(TDCBF_OK_BUTTON) | ButtonActive(TDCBF_RETRY_BUTTON) | ButtonActive(TDCBF_CLOSE_BUTTON);
    config.pszMainIcon = SetIcon();

    int button = 0;
    TaskDialogIndirect(&config, &button, NULL, NULL);
    return button;
}
```

Comment: Did you ensure that the v6 manifest was activated at the point you called TaskDialogIndirect? (There are various ways to accomplish this, but it depends on the structure of your program.)

Comment: Yes. is located at the top of the file: '#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")'

Comment: This establishes the bindings, but did you activate the context? The manifest context is activated by default for executables, but DLLs must activate them manually.

Comment: Without all of this it wouldn't work at all. It does work. But when I create dialogs there's a low chance that an empty window will pop up

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem in action. For instance, what is `ButtonActive()`, and what does `TaskDialogCallback` do? Are you customizing the dialog in some way? What you have shown does not appear like a standard TaskDialog window.

Comment: Okay, let me ask the question again: Is your code in an executable or a DLL? Because executables activate the manifest automatically, but DLLs must do it manually.

Comment: A window that suddenly does not display its content anymore after running for a while suggests at a resource handle leak.  Use Task Manager, Processes tab and add the Handles, User Objects and GDI Objects columns.  A steadily increasing number for one of these tells the tale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the flag TDF_ENABLE_HYPERLINKS. Adding hyperlinked text that is too long caused the dialog to spawn outside of the desktop view.